# How we can merge dictionaries having same 'id' with the condition to merge 'test_type' values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, merge

How can we merge the dictionary having same 'id' and with condition to merge 'test_type' values?

Input:

```
[{id:'abc', type:'test', test_type:['404']}, 
 {id:'def', type:'test', test_type:['404','server_error']},
 {id:'abc', type:'test', test_type:['server_error']},
 {id:'abc', type:'test', test_type:['server_error', '404']}]
```

Expected output:

```
[{id:'abc', type:'test', test_type:['404','server_error']}, 
 {id:'def', type:'test', test_type:['404','server_error']}]
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Also, how is `type` handled? And btw, your input is invalid python.

Comment: Looks pretty straightforward, just do it. If it doesn't work, add your code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
original_list = [{id:'abc', type:'test', 'test_type':['404']}, 
{id:'def', type:'test', 'test_type':['404','server_error']},
{id:'abc', type:'test', 'test_type':['server_error']},
{id:'abc', type:'test', 'test_type':['server_error', '404']}]
new_list = []
new_dict = {}
for old_dict in original_list:
    if old_dict[id] not in new_dict:
        new_dict[old_dict[id]] = old_dict
    else:
        present_values = new_values = []
        if 'test_type' in new_dict:
            present_values = new_dict[old_dict[id]]['test_type']
        if 'test_type' in old_dict:
            new_values = old_dict['test_type']
        temp_list = list(set(present_values + new_values))
        new_dict[old_dict[id]]['test_type'] = temp_list

final_list = list(new_dict.values())        
print(final_list)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clean way to do this using `itertools.groupby` (for creating dictionary groups based on key) and `collections.defaultdict` (for merging dictionaries).

Please find the explanation as inline comments. Feel free to ask any questions in the comments.

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import defaultdict

f = lambda x: x['id'] #condition for sorting & grouping
groups = groupby(sorted(l, key=f), f) #creating grouper object

output = []
for _ , g in groups:
  d = defaultdict(list)
  for i in g:
      d['id'], d['type'] = i['id'], i['type'] #set id and type as same
      d['test_type'].extend(i['test_type'])   #extend list of test_type
  d['test_type'] = list(set(d['test_type']))  #reset test_type as unique values
  output.append(dict(d))
```

```
[{'id': 'abc', 'test_type': ['404', 'server_error'], 'type': 'test'},
 {'id': 'def', 'test_type': ['404', 'server_error'], 'type': 'test'}]
```